# Mathematica 11.3 on Ubuntu & XFCE crashes

Tags: front-end, crash, linux, version-11.3, ubuntu

I have recently upgraded from version 10 to 11.3 on my group's server (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
Up until now, we have all used VNC(Xfce) connections to use the various programs on the server.
With the new install, I can't run Mathematica on the VNC(Xfce) due to the following error:

> Mathematica has received the signal: SIGSEGV and has exited.

However, If I connect via ssh with X-Forwarding enabled, everything works.
Is there a way to get the VNC to work again?
Our use cases involve running long simulations remotely...

Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution online.

Comment: Not a solution, just wanted to note that command line mode may be better for running long simulations than using the front end.

Comment: It may be a good idea to contact Wolfram Support about this though.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm waiting to see if anyone else already has a solution prior to starting a discussion with Wolfram :\
But thank you for your comment, CLI definitely has its uses.